# Running a background process with Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to send GET requests but before starting the requests, I'd like to capture the traffic. Capturing traffic can be done with the command:

```
dumpcap -i eth0 -f "udp port 53" -w dns.cap
```

in the background. While I capture packets, I need to make some request by sending some URLs. For now, with the code below, it seems my capturing code does not work, I can not even see a dns.cap file in my folder.

What's the problem?

```
import requests
import os
import subprocess
import urllib
print "start capturing packets...\n"
#os.system("dumpcap -i eth0 -f \"udp port 53\" -w dns.cap"
os.spawnl(os.P_NOWAIT,'dumpcap -i eth0 -f \"udp port 53\" -w dns.cap')
print urllib.urlopen('http://www.google.com').read()
#resp = requests.get('http://httpbin.org')
#resp=requests.get('http://httpbin.org')
print "ok"
```

Comment: Do you run the script as root? Try to specify full path to 'dns.cap' file.

Comment: yes as a root, no luck after specifying the exact path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.spanwl` is considered old and should be replaced with `subprocess.Popen`. Replace `os.spanwnl` call with this:

```
subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/dumpcap', '-i', 'eth0', '-f', 'udp port 53', 
                  '-w', '/tmp/dns.cap'])
```

It's better to add some pause (sleep) after starting the dumpcap to ensure that capturing is established when you make requests.

Comment: i tested, it works thanks, what about following code is there any difference than your post. subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/dumpcap', '-i eth0', '-f', 'udp port 53', '-w', '/tmp/dns.cap']), In addition my other code while processing packets really long is there easy way to adapt subprocess.Popen while using long system commands with arguments?

Comment: `'-i eth0'` will not work, you need to specify each argument in separate array item. There is no problem with long system commands with arguments. You can write `'-i', 'eth0'` in 2 array items, and you can write `'--long-command=eth0'` in a single array item.